# Extending the bot in python's IRC library

Tags: python, bots, irc

I am attempting to extend the example bot that comes with this [IRC library here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/irc). I've repasted the code of said bot [here](http://pastebin.com/Ex8kk03D).

My problem is that I don't quite see what needs to be modified in order to enable the bot to respond to events, like getting a message - there's no event dispatcher that I can see.

What I can do is

```
bot = irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot(server_list = [('irc.whatever.net.', 6667)],realname = 'irclibbot',nickname = 'irclibbot',)
bot.start()
```

and it runs fine - connects to the network and all that, but it doesn't do anything. Doesn't even respond to the basic CTCP events like VERSION and PING.

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this example](https://github.com/jaraco/irc/blob/master/scripts/testbot.py) of what you need to do.

```
class TestBot(irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot):
    def __init__(self, channel, nickname, server, port=6667):
        irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot.__init__(self, [(server, port)], nickname, nickname)
    def on_nicknameinuse(self, c, e):
        c.nick(c.get_nickname() + "_")

    def on_welcome(self, c, e):
        c.join(self.channel)

    def on_privmsg(self, c, e):
        self.do_command(e, e.arguments[0])
```

Define your own class that inherits from the actual `irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot` class. Then, the events will automatically be bound to the methods named `on_'event'` like `on_privmsg`, `on_part`, etc.

[Here](https://github.com/jaraco/irc/blob/master/irc/events.py) you can find the reference of the supported events.